# Strange behavior with caching

Tags: caching

I have added an output caching rule to cache .ttf files in my website as in attached image cacherule.jpg

As in attached image browsercache.jpg the browser is not caching the .ttf files while it's caching other file type that don't have a rule set for them.

If i remove the cache rule for .ttf file , the browser will cache the files now so it actually working contrary to what i expected.
[Cache rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljkw0.jpg)

[Browser with cache rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GogZY.jpg)

[Browser with no cache rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwEdh.jpg)

Please help with that.
Regards
Nader